# Authentication issue when uploading video to YouTube using YouTube API and cron

Tags: python, youtube, cron, youtube-api, youtube-data-api

I am trying to upload a video to YouTube each afternoon using the sample YouTube Python upload script from Google (see Python code examples on developers.google, I haven't enough reputation to post more links...). I would like to run it as a cronjob. I have created the client_secrets.json file and tested the script manually. It works fine when I run it manually, however when I run the script as a cronjob I get the following error:

> To make this sample run you will need to populate the
>   client_secrets.json file found at:
>
> /usr/local/cron/scripts/client_secrets.json
>
> with information from the Developers Console
>   https://console.developers.google.com/
>
> For more information about the client_secrets.json file format, please
>   visit:
>   https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/python/guide/aaa_client_secrets

I've included the information in the JSON file already and the -oauth2.json file is also present in /usr/local/cron/scripts.

Is the issue because the cronjob is running the script as root and somehow the credentials in one of those two files are no longer valid? Any ideas how I can enable the upload with cron?

Cheers
James

Answer (score 2):

Ok, so 7 months later I've come back to this cron issue. It turns out that the `upload2youtube.py` example file was hardcoded to look in the current directory for the `clients_secrets.json` file. This explains why I could run it manually from the local directory but not on cron. I've included the full path in the example file and this works fine now.